# Read code in a Crystal Reports xi file?

Tags: crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

My customer asked if I could convert several reports written in CR xi to SSRS 2008 format. I do not own a copy of CR and wonder if there is a way to legally and inexpensively review the design? I want to see how the old reports were constructed so that I can translate them into SSRS code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a free trial available from SAP [here](http://www.crystalreports.com/share/). If you own a copy of Visual Studio you can also get the Crystal Reports add-in from SAP. You can get it [here](http://www.sap.com//solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/index.html) but may have to search for other versions depending on your VS.

Hope that helps,

Chris